# How to nest custom argument parser instance in argparse

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I'm trying to nest multiple custom ArgumentParser I've created (and tested), into a bigger argument parser.

Think of it as having multiple independent components for a script, that each have its own options. I've created an ArgumentParser for each, tested whether they work correctly with unittests, and want to piece together a "mother" argument parser that gets all of the options at once, but is component based. Each component has some required options that will make it a hassle if I want to unify them under groups.

So my current pseudocode is like this:

```
def create_custom_parser1():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--component1-argument1')
    ...

def create_custom_parser2():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--component2-argument2')
    ...

def create_unified_parser():
    unified = ArgumentParser()
    component1_parser = create_custom_parser1()
    component2_parser = create_custom_parser2()
    # somehow do this:
    # unified.add_parsers([component1_parser, component2_parser])
```

EDIT: My command is super long (it's a machine learning training pipeline cli), but it has multiple independent component (e.g. preprocessing component, modelling component,etc). What I want is to have a unified command with all of the component parsers sewn together, but I want to start from independent parsers to keep my sanity and make each testable independently.

Comment: argparse only provides 2 such tools, `parents` and `subcommands`

Comment: @hpaulj I want to run all of these independent components sequentially by running the cli. Is it possible in this way? the subcommands I think is for having multiple possible commands, but here I have a super long command that has multiple components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parents` mechanism copies `Actions` from the parents to the new parser.  It's intended as a way of incorporating 'imported' parsers, without knowing what's in them (though it isn't hard to discover that). It may be worth searching SO for past experiences with it.

Subcommands/parsers, passes the parsing action to the new parser (as you note, only one).  There are lot more SO questions about it.  It cannot use predefined parsers (though I've seen a bug/issue request for such a feature).  But a predefined parser could be used as a `parent`.

You could call all parsers independently.  A `parse_args()` does not change the `sys.argv`, so multiple parsers can use the same list.  `parse_known_args` is better for this, so a parser doesn't quit over unrecognized strings. Also no-required (default) `optionals` are best.  Usually though, multiple parsers is an error, when a user doesn't realize that some imported module (e.g. a google youtube app) is looking at the commandline as well.

Or you could look at `sys.argv` before, and split it into sublists that you pass on to different parsers, e.g. `parser1.parse_args(part_argv)` etc.

Comment: handling it manually using sys.argv is I think a bad pattern, the parent or having a list of parsers is actually a good thing, using parse known_args.